# How to prevent sails.js from passing the req object on all views?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I noticed that **sails.js** passes the `req` object to ALL views, and doing that, to my understanding, is not the default behavior on **Express** (which sails is based on).

I can't find anything on the documentation. Is there any way to prevent sails from doing this? I mean, I don't see the need to pass such as huge object every time.

Thanks

Comment: objects are passed around by reference, and it happens in a million other places behind the scenes in node, express, and sails.js. it's fast. don't worry about it.

Comment: I didn't know about that. It was quite a silly concern now that I get that, I must admit. I still think this should be mentioned in the sails documentation (the fact that the reference gets passed by default), since it might be confusing, especially if you are learning express stuff and are told that views aren't supposed to "see" the req object, but that's another topic. Thank you.

Comment: sails has nothing to do with this. it's a feature of the actual Javascript language

Comment: Oh no, I mean, the fact that the req object gets passed to all views by default. As in, the reference to the req object (now that I know it's just a reference). It's not annoying or anything, just was a bit confusing at first after reading that res gets passed to views but not req (in express)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript passes objects by reference. The actual contents of `req` is stored once internally and all the `req` variables you find are just referring to the same object in memory. I'm not familiar with **sails.js**, but I'm guessing it's getting passed for convenience.

Comment: Whoa, so an object only ever gets stored in a certain place in memory once and whenever properties are added/modified, you're modifying that certain place in memory? Is that why you sometimes have to use _.clone? So whenever you say `var reference = object`, you are actually giving the var the object's "address"? Sorry if I seem redundant, just want to see if I get it, and sorry if I misused terms. And yeah, I guess it just gets passed for convenience. It was actually confusing at first, since other frameworks don't do that.

Comment: You are exactly right. Test it out in the Node console: var test = {a:1}; var test2 = test; test2.a = 2; console.log(test.a); Will output 2

Comment: That's interesting. This definitely helps me understand JavaScript better, thanks.